# Angular 2 - Counter increments all items when it should only increment selected item

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to use 2 way binding to increment a counter in Angular 2. The counter increments correctly, but it increments every item in the cart with the same value. I would like to increment each item in the cart with it own individual counter. I assume I should use @input/@output to resolve this issue, but I can't wrap my head around it. Please assist.

**estimate-detail.component.html**

```
     <tr *ngFor=" let item of Items">
            <td>
            <a cart-button [item]="item" action="remove" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">X</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{item.itemName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.rate}}</td>
            <td>
            <div class="btn-group">

           <custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue"></custom-counter>

            </div>
            </td>
            <td>${{item.rate*counterValue | number: '.2'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <td colSpan="4" class="text-right">Total</td>
          <td>${{ items | cartTotal | number: '.2'}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>
    </div>
```

**estimate-detail.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-estimate-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/components/estimateDetail/estimate-detail.component.html'
})

export class EstimateDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() estimate: Estimate;
    @Input() item: Item;  
    @Input() contact: Contact[];
    title="Estimate Details";
    counterValue = 1;
    selectedContact:string;
    Items:Item[];
    newEstimate = false;
    startDate:any;
    error: any;
    navigated = false; // true if navigated here


    constructor(
        private estimateService: EstimateService,
        private itemService:ItemService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
            this.startDate = new Date();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItems();
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = params['id'];
            if (id === 'new') {
                this.newEstimate = true;
                this.estimate = new Estimate();
            } else {
                this.newEstimate = false;
                this.estimateService.getEstimate(id)
                    .then(estimate => this.estimate = estimate);
            }
        });
    }
```

**counter.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-counter',
  template: `
    <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
    <span>{{counter}}</span>
    <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
  `
})
export class CustomCounterComponent {
 counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a single counterValue in your EstimateDetailComponent, but you want each item to have its own counter value. So counterValue should be a field of Item, not a field of the component. And it should be `[(counter)]="item.counterValue"`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm.